# How to convert List<String> to Dictionary<int,String>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dictionary

I have `List<String>`, i need to convert it to `Dictionary<int,String>` with auto generation of Key, is any shortest way to accomplish that? I have tried:

```
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, String>();
    int index = 0;
    list.ForEach(x=>{
      definitions.Add(index, x);
      index++;
});
```

but i think it is dirty way.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

```
var dict = list.Select((s, i) => new { s, i }).ToDictionary(x => x.i, x => x.s);
```

Comment: this starts the key from 0; what if I wanted to start from any other number, like 10 and also increment by 10 not 1;

Comment: @zak what did you get when you used **Skip** and **Where** ?

Comment: What if the list has duplicate keys and I just want to ignore adding the duplicate  to dictionary?

Comment: slight variation, using unnamed tuples (C# 7):
var dict = list.Select((s, i) => (s, i)).ToDictionary(x => x.i, x => x.s);

Answer (score 18):

I find this to be the neatest

```
int index = 0;
var dictionary = myList.ToDictionary(item => index++);
```

Comment: Boy this is a lot simpler than the accepted answer - why make it so complex just to get it into a single line?

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion, what you have is more readable than the Linq way (and as a bonus, it happens to be more efficient):

```
foreach(var item in list)
    dictionary[index++] = item;
```

Comment: there is a hidden pitfall when using the assignment operator like this: `dictionary[index++] = item;` existing keys will be silently overriden! When using the `Add` method it will throw an exception that the key already exists and at least notify the programmer somehow at runtime. It always depends on the usecase ;) as usual

Comment: @MongZhu I wouldn't call it hidden or silent.  When we say `dict[key1] = value1`, if `key1` already exists, the element will be overwritten. If it doesn't exist, a new element will be created. That's how dictionary normally works, and it's [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.item?view=net-6.0).

In this case here, the dictionary is a new empty instance, so there are no existing keys.

Comment: I know that it is documented. After my collegue fell into this trap we read the documentation ;) but only after that :D "the dictionary is a new empty instance, so there are no existing keys" yes this is what I meant with depending on the use case. in this case it is a very valid approach

Comment: @MongZhu you're right, something being documented doesn't always mean it's obvious. I guess we'll just leave the documentation link here (above), and hopefully it helps someone else :)

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
var dict = list.Select((x, i) => new {x, i})
    .ToDictionary(a => a.i, a => a.x);
```